# How can I remove a line in one file on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to remove a line in one file on Rails. I found a method gsub_file, but it was an undefined method in Rails 4. It's like reverse method of insert_into_file of thor.

e.g.) app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Before

```
 *= require_tree . <- Needs to be removed!
 *= require_self
```

After

```
 *= require_self
```

This should be performed in Rails Application Template.

Comment: which line are you removing, and how do you identify the line

Comment: if u remove require_tree then other dependency files have to be specified manually. That can be the reason of your problem. Have a check.

Comment: @bjhaid, as I noted, the part I want to remove is " *= require_tree .".

Comment: @Dave, I know. After removing them, I will add other stylesheets manually. So removing the require_tree line doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: @gipcompany then delete the line, I am confused here, do you want to remove lines from a file dynamically or you want to remove line from the specified file??

Comment: That method has been deprecated. You can see its implementation here: http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Generator/Commands/Base/gsub_file, and implement it yourself

Comment: @bjhaid, I want to do this. gsub_file('app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss', / *= require_tree .\n/, ''). But unfortunatelly, gsub_file has been deprecated.

Comment: I just want to ask if you're sure you want to do what you think you want to do? it sounds like a bad idea, but then again I don't know the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are implementing an application template (for use with the `rails new myapp -m` option), try using the Thor `gsub_file`, like this:

```
gsub_file 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.css', /*= require_tree .\n/, ""
```

Take a look at the [rails_apps_composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer) gem if you'd like to see lots of file manipulation using Thor.